# How should I organize my life towards a PhD in the next year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, university, graphics

After graduating and working for a few months I decided that I will quit my job to pursue a master's and then a PhD.

Before doing any applications I want to spend time reading the literature in computer graphics (what I want to study) and select a few topics and potential supervisors to then apply to their schools. And I also want to implement some papers in the field both to understand them better and to add them to my portfolio.

I want to spend at least 6 months just doing this process of reading papers and teaching myself as much math as possible.

My main concern is that on paper, what I would have done is stop working after 6 months and then not work for another 6. Ultimately I want to maximize the chances of getting approved for a master's at whichever university I finally go to. And although idealistically I know what I need to do to learn more and be more prepared to do research, I am very scared universities may see this as a sign of laziness.

I have been going to paper readings at the university of Toronto to try to be more exposed to current research. But once I quit my job I will have to move to a cheaper city and won't be able to do that.

Is there anything I can do, short of solving a millennium problem, to maximize my chances of being approved for a grad program?

Comment: Are there research jobs in academia for people with a bachelors' degree in your field?

Comment: There probably are, but most companies where I could actually learn anything important will prefer masters and PhD's, such is the case for any major videogame company, Nvidia, AMD...

Comment: I wasn't asking about companies, I was asking about academia.

Comment: Ah, my bad I read the comment too quickly. I guess I have not really searched that much for those to give an answer. Although my expectation would be that universities would rather give those kinds of jobs to their own students, wouldn't they?

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't just apply now, rather than waiting?

Comment: @Buffy I don;t want to apply to any school just because of "prestige" or things like that. i want to take the time to identify who are the people I would like to study under and plan ahead.

For example just last week I learnt about an amazing researcher in Brazil whose work I find fascinating. 

Also I am living in Canada and currently do not have a citizenship, and I am trying to get that sorted before applying within the country to avoid paying international fees.

Comment: I think that in most countries, "getting that sorted out" (citizenship) isn't so easy. It can take years, not months. You would probably be an international student most places other than one in which you already hold citizenship. Depending on your field (and the country), fees can be waived for doctoral students.

Comment: I'm unclear on why you think you should stop working as opposed to reading up on the literature in your spare time.

Comment: @Buffy I have been living in Canada for about 6 years now. The time part is pretty much solved.

Comment: I'm getting confused, since you mention Brazil.

Comment: @Jon Custer, because learning high level math and working at the same time just doesn't work out. I am usually too tired at the end of the day to do anything meaningful. By that I mean I end up falling asleep while trying to read a paper.

Comment: @Buffy yes I mentioned a professor in Brazil whose work I am interested in. But I am also interested in Canadian professors. I just want to sort my residency here before applying for Canadian universities

Comment: @Jon Custer also I don't just want to read them. I want to implement them. And that takes time I don't have much of.

Comment: Learning 'high level math' and working on implementations of problems is what you should be doing in grad school. If you aren't a competitive applicant now, you won't be after 6 months of doing nothing. When you tell a prospective supervisor that you quit your job to read on the internet the alarm bells in their head will be loud enough to hear from across the room.

Comment: @CJ59 The point isn't "doing nothing". The point is reading papers, textbooks (which I am already reading) and implementing the most interesting on these to take them apart and think how I could improve them. 

The point isn't sitting around without doing anything, quite the opposite, I would probably be spending more time working than I am now.

Comment: I don't believe you and the people you're interviewing with won't believe you either.

Comment: @CJ59 Good thing that neither you nor them will have to believe anything, because the implementations and reports will be evidence enough of how that time was invested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Get a job that allows you to do work in or related to the field you are interested in studying in** - in a worst case scenario, do such work as a volunteer.

Self-study work you do is *highly highly unlikely to be any value* to an admissions committee, regardless of any "reports" or "implementations" or other work you attempt to produce - no one will have time to review things like that.

What you need to do is build evidence that you are capable of doing academic research. Evidence means *references* - people in positions where they can vouch for your knowledge and capability. Self-study will provide you with no references. **Spend a little time searching around Academia.SE for all of the people who are asking what to do when they don't have enough references and are trying to apply to graduate school.** Don't get in their position, there are few answers.

The ideal jobs would be in academic labs doing work similar to what you want to do in grad school under greater supervision. At my institution, these positions are typically called "research interns" (though they are paid positions) or "research specialist" - I have also seen titles like "junior scientist/researcher" - these are positions that typically require a bachelors degree and often go to recent graduates of the institution but are available to others. However, depending on your field, these positions may be rare or not exist at all.

If there is no such position available in your field, you are still **much better off continuing to work another job** while doing self-study.

**Master's programs may require less research experience** - in that case, you are likely already in a position to apply to masters' programs, where you can get precisely the experience I am describing to prepare you for a PhD. This includes systems like in the U.S. where it is common in many fields for people to apply directly for PhD programs without a master's degree.